# Format of the .crt section in a Portable Executable (PE) file?

Tags: portable-executable

A Windows exe file may contain a .crt section.

The [Portable Executable (PE) data specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) defines the format of many sections (.edata, .idata, .rsrc, .pdata, etc) but it does not define the format of the .crt section. Where can I find the specification of the format of the .crt section?

Comment: no any special format here. we can declare any self named section. what will be it format ?  the section name at all can be any and no any format for any name. in *.crt* some crt data.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization?view=vs-2019